# Which planktonic foraminifera are found in both the Arctic and the Antarctic?

Tags: marine-biology

I want to investigate the influence of glacial melting on the <sup>18</sup>O signature of foraminifera shells. I want to compare the Arctic (which is melting rapidly) and the Antarctic (which has just started melting). For this I need a foraminiferal species that occurs both in the Atlantic in the Arctic and in the Antarctic.

For the Arctic I have found Neogloboquadrina pachyderma and Turborotalita quinqueloba but I don't know if they also occur in the Antarctic. Does anyone have a publication or database on this? It does not have to be the mentioned foraminifera species, it can also be other species.

By the way, we are talking about planktonic foraminifera and not bentonic foraminifera. This means that they must live close to the water surface.

Many thanks :D

Comment: Did you come across the [FORCIS database](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41597-023-02264-2)?